# Multiple LiveData/StateFlow for one pair of Fragment-ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I have a Fragment, that represents a screen in a single activity app, and a ViewModel for this fragment.

**ViewModel** uses multiple repositories for loading a set of data from multiple API calls and emit this data to the fragment via **multiple StateFlow**.

Assume that the fragment has 2 views, each view is collecting data from a StateFlow related to it. Until all of the 2 views do not draw their data I want to show some progress bar, then when these views will receive data, animate the whole fragment visibility from invisible to visible.

My question is: how to correctly handle when all of 2 views received their data?

**Repository:**

```
class Repository(private val name: String) {
    private val _data = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val data = _data.asStateFlow()

    suspend fun load() {
        // load from the DB/API if no data
        // load fresh from the API if have data

        delay(1000)
        _data.emit("$name data")
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class ScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // will be injected by Dagger2/Hilt
    private val repository1 = Repository("Repository1")
    private val repository2 = Repository("Repository2")

    private val _flow1 = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    private val _flow2 = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    val flow1 = _flow1.asStateFlow()
    val flow2 = _flow2.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository1.data.collect {
                _flow1.emit(it)
            }
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository2.data.collect {
                _flow2.emit(it)
            }
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository1.load()
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository2.load()
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
class Screen : Fragment(/*layoutd*/) {
    private val viewModel: ScreenViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.flow1.filterNotNull().collect {
                draw1(it)
            }
        }
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.flow2.filterNotNull().collect {
                draw2(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun draw1(data: String) {
        // some stuff
    }

    private fun draw2(data: String) {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try calling your repositories inside a deferred call like 
`val call1 = async { repository1.load() }`
`val call2 = async { repository2.load() }`
`draw(call1.await(), call2.await())`
This ensures both the calls complete before calling the `draw` method. For handling the states, you can use the Resources wrapper or variation of it so that your UI can differentiate between states.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#addendum

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [BindingAdapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for this case.

First in my ViewModel file (outside ViewModel Class) I would create an `Enum Class`

```
class ScreenViewModel : ViewModel() { .... }
enum class LoadingStatus {
  LOADING,
  ERROR,
  FINISHED
}
```

Then I would create inside the ViewModel a MutableLiveData backed by LiveData to monitor the Loading status.

```
private val _status = MutableLiveData<LoadingStatus>()
  val status: LiveData<LoadingStatus>
    get() = _status
```

Inside the init block I would change the value of MutableLiveData

```
    init {
          viewModelScope.launch {
            
          try {
//before fetching data show progressbar loading
            _status.value = LoadingStatus.LOADING
            repository1.data.collect {
              _flow1.emit(it)
            
    
          }

//after fetching the data change status to FINISED
            _status.value = LoadingStatus.FINISHED
            }
          
          catch (e:Exception) {
            _status.value = LoadingStatus.FINISHED
            
          }
    }
```

On a separate Kotlin File I write the code for the **Binding Adapter** This makes the ProgressBar disappear depending on the status.

```
@BindingAdapter("apiLoadingStatus")
fun ProgressBar.setApiLoadingStatus(status:LoadingStatus?){

    when(status){

        LoadingStatus.LOADING -> {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
            
        }
        LoadingStatus.FINISHED -> {
           

            this.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        LoadingStatus.ERROR -> {
             this.visibility = View.GONE
        }

    }
}
```

Then include this code for ProgressBar's Fragmement XML. Note I use **DataBinding** here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- TODO: Add data binding node -->

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.yourPackageName.ViewModel" />

    </data>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statusImageView"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            app:apiLoadingStatus="@{viewModel.status}"
```

Basically for this code to work you need to enable **Databinding** and also add dependency for **ViewModel/LiveData** in the gradle file.

You can also write another BindingAdapter to change the fragment's views visibility from invisible to visible.

Comment: So, your suggestion is just to add another (third) StateFlow/LiveDate to observe and switch visibility from invisible to visible. But with this approach visibility may change regardless of finishing draw1 and draw2.